# Syntax error in getter / setter in computed property in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, laravel-mix

I've just read and apply the documentation about [Two-way Computed Property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html)
, but the compiler says that it is a syntax error.

This is my sample snippet:

```
computed: {
 message: {
  get () {
   return this.$store.state.obj.message
 },
  set (value) {
   this.$store.commit('updateMessage', value)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact message you're getting?

Comment: @red-X  `Unexpected token, expected ; (111:11)` that is from the `get() `

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this codeblock, I think your problem is somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i only have wrong interpretation in computed property in vue.

I call my computed property as:

```
message() {
  get () {
   return this.$store.state.obj.message
 },
```

The computed property named `message` was called as a function.